# Write onclick method that has parameters in php print function

Tags: javascript, php, printing, onclick

I'm having problems with writing an onclick method in php print in code below:

```
    <?php print "<p><small> <a  href='#' onclick='ajaxMenu('comments.php?news=".$fileContent['id']."');>".$number. " ".$text." </small> </a> </p>"; ?>
```

Given code doesn't work. I believe it's because of combination of single and double quotes in it. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Yes, the issue is the quotes. Your onclick is essentially just: `onclick='ajaxMenu('`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I knew that quotes were the problem, but I can't find a way to fix it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can escape " characters by having a forward slash \"

```
<?php echo( "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"onMenu('this is the menu');\">This is a link</a>" ); ?>
```

Comment: Missing a closing quote for the echo statement, but otherwise correct.